# What is the effect of UIP_CONF_BUFFER_SIZE in contiki_conf.h file

Tags: contiki

I am working on contiki for some time, and recently I faced a weird problem where I noticed that the cooja mote fails to receive any data packet larger than 57 bytes, for z1 mote the limit is something around 96 - 97 bytes (in cooja simulator) and in real hardware(mbxxx target) I've observed that this limit is 92 bytes. Anyone else faced similar situation, is this has something to do with platform specific configuration, and how do I change this? I've looked into contiki_conf.h file and found UIP_CONF_BUFFER_SIZE parameter. What is the effect if this parameter is changed?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and it seems like the maximum IP payload handled by the uip stack. Thus it sums up the 40 byte IP header + 8 byte UDP header + UDP payload size. Same would hold for TCP connections. So for example if th UIP_CONF_BUFFER_SIZE is set to 140, and if we ping the mote with an effective IP packet size more than 140, the mote will fail to respond!